# Add or Update MySQL Record without always updating date_modified column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this function below that I am using to either insert a new record into MySQL or Update the record if it already exists.

It is part of a Project management project I am building and now I have added in a field for task sort order.  So basically, if there is 100 task on a project and the user saves the data, it's going to make 100 SQL queries.  I don't love the idea but in this case I think it will be fine.

One thing that is bugging me though is I have a `date_modified` database column that is a DATETIME field.  Ideally I would like to only update this column when either a Task name, description, status, type, or priority changes.

I'm really not sure on the best approach to do this?  Any ideas?

Here is what I have right now....

```
public function addOrUpdateTaskRecord($taskId, $projectId, $name, $description, $status, $priority, $type, $date_entered, $date_modified, $sort_order, $heading){

    $sql = "
        INSERT INTO
            $this->tasksDbTableName(task_id, project_id, name, description, status, priority, type, date_entered, date_modified, sort_order, heading)
        VALUES
            ('$taskId', '$projectId', '$name', '$description', '$status', '$priority', '$type', UTC_TIMESTAMP(), UTC_TIMESTAMP(), '$sort_order', '$heading')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            name='$name',
            description='$description',
            status='$status',
            priority='$priority',
            type='$type',
            date_modified=UTC_TIMESTAMP(),
            sort_order='$sort_order',
            heading='$heading'";

     return $this->db->query($sql);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can put an expression in the set clause, and so have the logic right there:

```
date_modified = (case when name <> values(name) or
                           description <> values(description) or
                           status <> values(status) or
                           type <> values(type) or
                           priority <> values(priority)
                      then UTC_TIMESTAMP()
                      else date_modified
                 end)
```

Comment: This looks really interesting, like nothing I have ever done before! Could you possibly show how this could tie into my existing sql?  Thanks Ill do some research on this too

Comment: @jasondavis . . . Just replace `date_modified=UTC_TIMESTAMP()` with this statement.

Comment: I just tried this out, it seems it does not produce any errors and my update all work fine now except it just never updates the date_modified filed even when other field have changed and been updated.  Seems like it would give some sort of error, ill have to dig into this thanks

Comment: I will select this answer as it is ultimnately what I used but just a note, I had to move this block of code/SQL above all the other fields in the UPDATE section for it to work correctly, it took a few days to finally figure out that solution so maybe it will help someone if they ever read this answer and this comment, the order does seem to matter sometimes! Thanks